# Moving to Typescript, error with numbers

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I have a static app made using html, css, and jQuery. I am now importing it in to Angular 2, and i am getting issues with dates:

```
// GET DATE

let d = new Date();
let day = d.getDay() + 1;
let date = d.getDate() + 1;
let datePostFix;

// POST FIX DATE ST ND RD TH

if (date == 1 || date == 21 || date == 31 && date !== 11) {
    let datePostFix = "st"
} else if (date === 2 || date === 22 && date !== 12) {
    let datePostFix = "nd"
} else if (date === 3 || date === 23 && date !== 13) {
    let datePostFix = "rd"
} else {
    let datePostFix = "th"
}
```

Basically each if statement bugs out on the !== whatever. The error i get is [ts] Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types '31' and '11' but i don't understand as its a number.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain why you even have that? Obviously `date !== 11` if it is `1 | 21 | 31`

Comment: At least the check for inequality with 11, 12 and 13 is pointless and only applies to the last part. A number has to not be 11 if it is 31.

Comment: Also, I suspect that redefining let datePostFix as you have done is not really what you want here, given that you defined it uninitialised up top. You could just use var or skip the keyword on the usages within the if-blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is trying to save you from writing ineffective code. When it gets to the `date !== 11` part, it knows that `date` must be 1, 21, or 31 (and hence `date` has a type of `1 | 21 | 31`, which is a union type - see [Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)). It knows that none of those numbers can possibly equal 11, so it's trying to tell you that you shouldn't compare it to 11.

If you remove the `!==` comparisons, the code will behave exactly the same:

```
if (date == 1 || date == 21 || date == 31) {
    let datePostFix = "st"
} else if (date === 2 || date === 22) {
    let datePostFix = "nd"
} else if (date === 3 || date === 23) {
    let datePostFix = "rd"
} else {
    let datePostFix = "th"
}
```

Edit: as @missingmanual pointed out, `d.getDate() + 1` is almost certainly not what you want. In most cases, this will give you tomorrow's date (since `getDate()` already returns a number form 1-31). In some cases, this could even give you an invalid date (e.g. if today is the 31st, you will get 32)

Comment: Cheers for that. Yeah that does make perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you wanted to do:

```js
// GET DATE

let d = new Date();
let day = d.getDay() + 1;
let date = d.getDate() + 1;
let datePostFix: string;

// POST FIX DATE ST ND RD TH

if (date == 1 || date == 21 || date == 31) {
  datePostFix = "st"
} else if (date === 2 || date === 22) {
  datePostFix = "nd"
} else if (date === 3 || date === 23) {
  datePostFix = "rd"
} else {
  datePostFix = "th"
}
```

First let datePostFix is enough and there's no need to check that it's not 11, 12 or 13, sine as others mentioned you've already checked that it's 31, 22 or 23. 
Also not sure if adding 1 to getDate is what you've wanted as this would give you tomorrow's date.